# div with background fixed

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I am trying to add a div to my html with a box image in it. But I couldnt make the image to stretch to the div's size

here is what I have so far,

```
<div style="background:url('images/box.png') no-repeat center center fixed;width:600px;height:400px">
    test 
</div>
```

this displays a div with width 600px and height 400px but it displays half of the image. but I need to make the image to stretch.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the image to stretch, losing it's original aspect ratio, add `background-size: 100% 100%;`.

On the other hand, if you want the image to take up the entire div while maintaining image aspect ratio and some clipping is okay, use  `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 3):

use `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain` (choose the right property for your needs)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

> **cover**
>       This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.
>
> **contain**
>       This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.